An old Bollywood movie about a policeman and some thieves/criminals
This is an old black & white bollywood movie (possibly originally in Marathi) and I remember it being about a policeman who decides to live with some criminals/thieves to reform them and change their ways. There are a few trials such as the fields (with crops) being burned. In the end the policeman dies(? not sure). I think a picture or poster of the movie might have had 2 eyes on it.

Any more details you can provide? When did you watch it, how old is "old"? Any other descriptions or plot-details you remember?

Do Ankhen Barah Haath from 1957.
Source from Wiki

The film portrays a young jail warden, Adinath, who rehabilitates six dangerous prisoners released on parole into persons of virtue.
He takes these notorious, often surly, murderers and makes them work hard with him on a dilapidated country farm, rehabilitating them through hard work and kind guidance as they eventually produce a great harvest.
The film ends with the death of the warden at the hands of the minions of a corrupt enemy who wants no competition, in the profitable market he controls.

Poster of the movie might have had 2 eyes on it - mentioned by the OP

The meaning of the movie's title in English is Two Eyes, Twelve Hands



